# Should I write OpenGL program by using C or C++? Really confused

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Should I write OpenGL program by using C or C++? Really confused.

Comment: You haven't really told us enough to form the basis of an opinion. It'll depend on things like how well you know each language, what features unique to each language your program can use, and so on.

Comment: I am a beginner to OpenGL. just studying it. I wanna know which is better? C or C++???

Comment: What do you master best? C or C++ ?

Comment: Leman: I prefer C++; some people prefer C. The real question would be whether the rest of your program is particularly well suited to one or the other. C++ is a larger language, so learning it really well takes longer, but I believe  learning enough to use it reasonably well actually takes less time. There's a distinct difference in flavor and thinking style between the two though, so each suits different people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either. The OpenGL API is in C and C++ is backward compatible with C. Just choose your favourite language.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really provide enough information to give you a complete answer. But generically speaking, you could use either language to access the OpenGL API. There are some GUI toolkits with built in bindings to OpenGL. For example [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) (a c++ API) has the [QGLWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qglwidget.html) and I 
believe that [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) (a c API) has access to [OpenGL](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html) too.

In general, you should use the language that your are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL can be used with both, so take the language you're the most comfortable with.